# How to find the serial number on a 26 inch Jamas Trail X mountain bike

Tags: mountain-bike

Jamas Trail X powered by Fuze how can I tell what the year on the serial number is of the bike, and also would like to know about what it’s worth so again it’s a 26 inch Jamás trail X powered by Fuze the front shocks are 191 omnis it has a SRSunTour Kranks and sprocket it has SRAM Dash SX for back brakes with One to one Actuation ratio Andis SRAMSX4 back shifter it also has a SRAMSX 424 speed shifters on XC riser handlebars with tech trough front brake levers and it is also a 7005 aluminum frame

Comment: We don't do valuations - your bike is worth what someone is prepared to pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.jamisbikes.com/usa/register.html  says:

> Your Jamis serial number is located under the bottom bracket of your Jamis Bicycle.